# Android supporting multiple screens with Images

Tags: android, layout, android-screen-support

I read a lot about supporting multiple screens problems in Android, but I didn't solve mines yet. If I understood well, there are at least 2 ways to show images on different screens and to make it look normal. First, to make many images (xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, ldpi). Second, is to create layouts(big, medium, small and etc.) My question is: which method is better? Now, my problem. I took first method, create my image in different sizes and  copied to folders according to image's size. I used DEVS BITMAP app to get size, which I want my image to look like for different screens. I'm getting perfect view when I look on the 7' screen, but the view gets terrible on 3' screen. I copied this code to my Manifest:

```
 <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

I think it isn't necessary, but I wanted to be sure I am doing everything good. Could anyone answer my question and solve my problem? I would appreciate your help! ;)

Comment: Just adding images to their respective folders will not do. Their resolution too matters. The image is getting terrible , i am sure because of the image resolution. DPI is also of very importance

Comment: So how can I fix that?

Comment: Read the android documentation. You need to take high resolution pics    and compress them according to dpi's supported by different screen sizes.

Comment: And maybe you know a good way how to know what size of your image do you need for xdpi(mdpi, hdpi ant etc.) image size? One more question: how to easily convert your images for specific size? I could use android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/… but it converts with black lines in the borders and I have to rename each icon from "icon.9" to "icon"

Comment: You can use microsoft office to compress your images. Read Android Support Screen Documentation. Everything is written there

Comment: Do you suggest to read this one http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html ? I read it ant I  understood not everything because there are a lot of text and my englsh isn't so good. I read it before your comment and I get the main idea that you have to deal with sizes creating different layouts and images. But I didn't find the answer to my question.. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new Project.

There is a layout folder ,values-sw600dp,values-dw720dp-land. In both these folders, there is a dimens.xml file. What is written in it is this :-

```
<resources>

<!--
     Customize dimensions originally defined in res/values/dimens.xml (such as
     screen margins) for sw720dp devices (`e.g. 10" tablets)` in landscape here.
-->
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">128dp</dimen>
```

That mean folders with sw-720 dp are for 10 inch devices, similar 600dp are for 7 inch devices and default layout folders vary from 3 to 5 inch device.

**layout-sw600dp** -> This folder will have xml in PORTRAIL Orientation for 7 inch devices

**layout-sw600dp-land** -> This folder will have xml in LANDSCAPE Orientation for 7 inch devices. When you rotate your device, view will be formed from this folder

Based on the dpi/resoulution of your devices, you can create unlimited number of layout folders.

Similarly, there are folders for images called drawable ->hdpi ldpi mdpi xhdpi xxhdpi. Based on the resolution of devices, images are picked from their respective category.

**xxhdpi will contain images with the highest resolution**. So try to download big resolution images and downsize them and put them in the other folders.

Now how to know which device will take which image ? **See the image below :-**

See the drop down. It contains a list of devices with their resolutions and image type -hdpi ldpi mdpi xhdpi xxhdpi. Moreover, you can **GOOGLE** for the devices and their resolutions and dpi's.

So whatever app you are making for a device, choose that device and look at its resolution and see whether it is hdpi or ldpi etc. Accordingly, put the images and layouts.

This is my understanding. I create my layouts with this understanding. I hope you got a clear picture
[image]

Comment: Okay, thanks, now I understood ;) Now another problem came. I have "values-sw720dp", "values-sw600dp", "values-sw480dp", "values-sw320dp", "values-sw240dp" and "values" folders. In my layout emulator is nexus4 with 768x1280 density. I'm changing dimens in those folders and saw that when I change dimens in values-sw320dp folder my nexus4 emulator also changes. Maybe you know why? I think it should take dimens from values-sw720dp not from values-sw320dp ...

Comment: First of all it is 1280x768(Width/Height).This is the formula for calculating dpi -> dpi = sqrt(w^2 + h^2)/inches. Applying formula for nexus 4 -> sqrt(768^2 + 1280^2)/4.7 = 317. That is why it is taking from 320 folder .     Get it?

Comment: Yes, thank you. But doesn't sw means smallest width? If I have nexus 4 (768x1280) with screen 4.7 (so dpi = 317) and some other phone (240x432) with screen 3.4 (so dpi =145) why both of them getting dimens from values-sw320dp folder? I have values-sw240dp folder, so shouldn't second screen take from that?

Comment: You have defined only one dimension. if you define a dimension in the default values folder, then that other phone will take from that and i am sorry because nexus 4 is 768x1280 pixel

Comment: One more question: when android uses values folder's dimens (it's called normal)?

Comment: I have told you that devices till 4 inch use default folders in android. If you are creating for multiple devices then the other custom folders come in use

Comment: Okay, sorry, if I don't understand or understand not enough, but I changed dimens in "values" folder but none of screens hadn't change. I have 10 (from 2.7' to 10') screens in my layout to see how everything works but nothing happened when I changed something in dimens, "values" folder. Now about you second comment. So as far as I understood, android uses default values folder when you are not creating for multiple screens?

Comment: If you have a single screen then it uses values folder. Dude its quite confusing. Why don't you not use values folder and simple create layouts in different folders

Comment: I thought that it will be simpler and more seriously for programmer. Because when there a lot of layouts, there are a lot of code and I know that every programmer should write his code as shortest as he can, but if you say that making a lot layouts is good and popular solution for this, I will do this way :)

Answer (score 0):

### For Multiple Screen Support

Add Different size of images to 
drawable-ldpi/ 
drawable-mdpi/
drawable-hdpi/
drawable-xhdpi/
drawable-xxhdpi/

Suppose you have Imageview in layout folder

```
  <ImageView
       android:layout_width="@dimen/horizontal_len"
       android:layout_height="@dimen/vertical_len" />
```

Do the following values

values/dimens.xml (Normal mobile)

```
<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
<dimen name="horizontal_len">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="vertical_len">16dp</dimen>
```

values-large/dimens.xml  (7 inch)

```
<dimen name="horizontal_len">20dp</dimen>
<dimen name="vertical_len">20dp</dimen>
```

values-xlarge/dimens. xml (10 inch)

```
<dimen name="horizontal_len">22dp</dimen>
<dimen name="vertical_len">22dp</dimen>
```

So you have to try like this.

Comment: I copied, but activity_main layout shows me error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_width' with value '@dimens/width'). Btw, my ImageView looks like this: 
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
        android:layout_width="@dimens/width"
        android:layout_height="@dimens/height"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="35"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

Comment: Use @dimen not "@dimens"

Comment: And maybe you know a good way how to know what size of your image do you need for xdpi(mdpi, hdpi ant etc.) image size? One more question: how to easily convert your images for specific size? I could use http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html but it converts with black lines in the borders and I have to rename each icon from "icon.9" to "icon"